# Get all rows where field matches another field in another table in django

Tags: django

Say that I have a table called watchlist, this contains a list of entities that I'm really concerned about:

```
class Watchlist(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity)
    objects = WatchlistManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.entity)
```

And say I have a list of alerts:

```
class DistinctAlert(models.Model):
    alert_type = models.ForeignKey(AlertType, db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    entities = models.ManyToManyField(to='Entity', db_index=True, through='EntityToAlertMap')
    has_unattended = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    latest_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
```

Disregarding what alert type is I'm trying to get all DistinctAlerts as long as the entity exists in the watchlist.

Something like this:

```
DistinctAlert.objects.filter(entities__in=Watchlist.objects.all()).all()
```

But of ocurse this doesn't work since they require entity objects instead of watchlist objects. What's the best approach for this? Should I do:

```
DistinctAlert.objects.filter(entities__in=[element.entity for element in self.all()]).all()
```

Not sure if iterating over every element and constructing the list outside is the right way to do it, or if it's possible to pass a queryset like so:

```
DistinctAlert.objects.filter(entities__in=Watchlist.objects.all()).all()
```

(the above example wouldn't work for me since they're watchlist objects and not entity objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the backwards relation from `Entity` to `Watchlist`:

```
DistinctAlert.objects.filter(entities__watchlist__isnull=False)
```